# Why isn't the response from Ajax showing?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm passing values using ajax from a web page to a php file. The purpose is to pass database credentials to be able to test the database connection and get the result in return. I'm passing server name, username and password to the php file. The problem is that I'm not able to see the database connection response from the php file.

This is how I call the function within document ready:

```
$('#dbconn').click(db_connect)
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
function db_connect(dbserver, dbuser, dbpassword) {
            var dbserver;
            var dbuser;
            var dbpassword;
            dbserver = $('input:dbserver').val();
            dbuser = $('input:dbuser').val();
            dbpassword = $('input:dbpassword').val();
            $.ajax({
            url   : "script/create_db.php", 
            type  : "POST",
            cache : false,
            data  : {
            dbserver : dbserver,
            dbuser : dbuser,
            dbpassword: dbpassword,
            success: function(result){alert ("response")}
            }
            });
        };
```

And this is my php code:

```
$servername  = $_GET["dbserver"];
$username = $_GET["dbuser"];
$password = $_GET["dbpassword"];
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else{
 echo "Connection succsess";
 }
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Check how you're sending the ajax and look at how you are retrieving the data in php :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> success: function(result){alert ("response")}
> ```

When you get the response you alert the string "response".

You ignore the value of `result` entirely.

You don't see the response because you aren't looking for it.

Comment: I hope the mistake is not that silly. If OPs is not even seeing the "response" alert perhaps a error: function might help debug.

Comment: I don't know if it belongs in your post; but there's a mess up in the type being sent and being read.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript — The selectors for getting the values are wrong too, but the OP said they couldn't see the response, so the various other issues are by the by for the time being.

Comment: Didn't even notice that :) thanks for clarifying the rules anyway

Comment: I appreciate all your feedback. I am trying to learn this programming, so specific pointers to my errors in the scripts would be great